# for loop for calculations from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have a text file which I have turned into a dataframe.  I'm basically just trying to loop over every value from column H and Z, square each of them and then take the square root (Pythagoras' theorem in other words).  I.E.

```
F = sqrt(H**2 + Z**2).
```

My data:(after its been turned into a pandas dataframe)

```
    H        D       Z
0   3235     6764    9546
1   1667     3455    7776
2   3555     3564    5433
3   2344     3333    8777
4   5666     3334    4444
```

That's a tiny snippet of the data.  There are about 1000> rows of data here.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

#load data:

df=pd.read_table('example_data.txt', sep='\s+')

from math import sqrt
for x,y in df:
    F=sqrt(H**2+Z**2)
    print(F)
```

The error produced:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-1b1be5be91d0> in <module>()
        1 from math import sqrt
  ----> 2 for x,y in df:
        3     F=sqrt(H**2+Z**2)
        4     print(F)
        5 

        ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

So that's it.  This is an easy question I feel, but one a Python beginner can't seem to solve.  Its essentially repeating a calculation many times over with 2 variables.  I've seen it with 1 variable but not 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers!

Comment: What are `x, y` in the for loop?
ps: you may want to check the apply/applymap method on dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `numpy` to vectorise this:

```
In[11]:
df['F'] = np.sqrt(df['H']**2 +  df['Z']**2)
df

Out[11]: 
      H     D     Z             F
0  3235  6764  9546  10079.252998
1  1667  3455  7776   7952.676593
2  3555  3564  5433   6492.727778
3  2344  3333  8777   9084.605935
4  5666  3334  4444   7200.881335
```

Regarding your error, the iterable returned from a `DataFrame` are the columns:

```
for col in df:
    print(col)

H
D
Z
F
```

hence the error, to iterate over the rows you use `iterrows`:

```
from math import sqrt
for x,y in df.iterrows():
    F=sqrt(y['H']**2+y['Z']**2)
    print(F)

10079.252998114493
7952.676593449529
6492.72777806062
9084.605935317173
7200.881334947827
```

but for simple arithmetic operations you should avoid loops and look for vectorised solutions such as `numpy` it will be much faster than looping and scale better when the data size increases.

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas/Numpy/SciPy we always prefer vectorized solutions as they are much faster, look better and the code looks much cleaner and shorter.

So try to use [numpy.linalg.norm()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) instead of looping:

```
In [34]: df['res'] = np.linalg.norm(df[['H','Z']], axis=1)

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
      H     D     Z           res
0  3235  6764  9546  10079.252998
1  1667  3455  7776   7952.676593
2  3555  3564  5433   6492.727778
3  2344  3333  8777   9084.605935
4  5666  3334  4444   7200.881335
```

Comment: This is the (or, a) correct way to do the task, yes, but the answer itself doesn't seem to be of any help as far as actually answering the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

iterating over a `DataFrame` iterates over the column labels (like the default `dict` iterator iterates over the keys). To iterate over the rows, you need `iterrows`, or preferable `itertuples`.

Iteration is heavily discouraged, though because it is slow.

This operation is pretty easy to do column-wise, so iteration is not necessary

```
(df['H']**2 + df['Z']**2).pow(.5)
```